# "The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed" - how to ignore?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

I asked a question a while back about seamless updates:

[Seamless EF Migrations from Staging > Production with Schema Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669620/seamless-ef-migrations-from-staging-production-with-schema-change)

I think a simple way to achieve this is to simply suppress the error `The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed` - this way I can

1. Publish my app to a staging slot
2. Test migration against a staging db
3. Swap staging/production
4. Migrate directly to Prod

This is what I do now, but between `3` and `4`, there are a few seconds where the dbContext throws that error.  If I could simply suppress that error... we could eliminate 95% of those errors across those few seconds (the 5% being errors that we catch resulting from the drifted model).

**Is there a way to suppress this error but keep migrations enabled?**

Update:

Using the link [here](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/) I was able to test out the following:

```
    public ApplicationContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection") {
        this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        Database.SetInitializer(new SuppressedInitializer<ApplicationContext>());
    }


public class SuppressedInitializer<TContext> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
where TContext : DbContext {
    public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context) {
        if (!context.Database.Exists()) {
            throw new ConfigurationException(
              "Database does not exist");
        }
        else {
            if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)) {
                var contextException = new InvalidOperationException("The database is not compatible with the entity model.");
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(contextException);
                // intentionally don't throw so that the application may continue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`contextException` is created when I expect it to and I believe this is a solution.

Comment: This may help. Basically you can test if the model is compatible and take whatever action you require. https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/

Comment: @SteveGreene interesting - is this approach compatible with the current version of EF?

Comment: Works in EF 6. Not sure about core.

Comment: @SteveGreene - just tried it out and it's not working.  Dug around and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703810/how-to-disable-migration-in-entity-framework-4-3-1

Comment: What's not working? I have it in multiple PROD apps. You do need to check before you initialize the context. I have mine in the STATIC constructor.

Comment: @SteveGreene - `SetInitializer` was unavailable from my context.  Placing it in the constructor works - but then `TransactionScope` throws errors around constructor arguments (should be initialized with 0, 1 is provided).  Removing the `using` gets everything compiling... but then suppression doesn't work.  Adding code into my question with details.

Comment: @SteveGreene - the exception thrown was actually from my tweaked model, so I believe this works.  One concern I have is around `TransactionScope` being removed - is that essential?  Either way - feel free to add this all in an answer of your own so I can accept and get you some more rep for this :)

Comment: Static constructor (not the regular constructor), right?

Comment: @SteveGreene actually - the regular one.  Updating my question with details.

Comment: I prefer static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727585/database-setinitializer-to-null-not-working-entity-framework-4-3-1-code-first#16727643